# Should styling a ListView affect its elements?

Tags: android, user-interface, android-styles

I read about Android styles and themes today and tried to apply it to a list in my app as a test.  The app has a list element which have TextViews added to it programmatically.

According to the docs applying a style as a theme affects child views too.

So I tried this:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"/>
```

I expected that the TextView texts in the list became small, but nothing happened.

I also tried `@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Headline1`, but it had no effect either.

Why is that?

I didn't change any of the style or theme settings myself. I use the default settings which Android Studio generated for the project.

Shouldn't applying a style as a theme to a view like above change something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the style "TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small" which is applicable to a TextView and not a generic one like ListView.

You need to apply the style to the list **item** which is the TextView. You can create a custom style for text appearance, font, sizing, etc and reuse it in your entire app.

If you are creating your views programmatically, you can use a custom adapter (which extends your default adapter), override getView method to apply your style. Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3255794/1300813)

Refer to [this](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/whats-your-text-s-appearance-f3a1729192d) awesome article by @Nick Butcher

Comment: The problem is I don't create the TextViews. The ListView creates them itself from an array adapter. I thought by using android:theme the text appearance setting flows down the view hierarchy even if the list doesn't use it itself.

Comment: You can apply style programmatically in your code when your create the text view from the array adapter

Comment: You mean going through the list with `getItemAtPosition()`?  I haven't thought of that, but it can work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200035/discussion-between-mayuri-khinvasara-and-tom).